# impala find_in_set vs in performance

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, impala

could anyone tell me find_in_set() vs in() which one's performance is better  ?

```
SELECT a.data_date,
           lower(substr (a.cookie_id,-3,1)) cookie_type,
           CASE WHEN find_in_set (lower(substr (a.cookie_id,-3,1)),'2,3,5,6,8,b,c,d') > 0 THEN 'A' ELSE 'B'END 'AB',
           COUNT(a.cookie_id)
    FROM dw.dw_cookie_dau_visit a,  
    WHERE  a.data_date = '20181102'
    AND   a.site_id = 600
    AND   lower(substr(a.cookie_id,-1,1)) NOT IN ('e','f')
    AND   lower(substr(a.cookie_id,-3,1)) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f')
    GROUP BY a.data_date,cookie_type,AB;

SELECT a.data_date,
           lower(substr (a.cookie_id,-3,1)) cookie_type,
           CASE WHEN lower(substr (a.cookie_id,-3,1) in ('2', '3', '5', '6', '8', 'b', 'c', 'd')   THEN 'A' ELSE 'B'END 'AB',
           COUNT(a.cookie_id)
    FROM dw.dw_cookie_dau_visit a,   
    WHERE a.data_date = '20181102'
    AND   a.site_id = 600
    AND   lower(substr(a.cookie_id,-1,1)) NOT IN ('e','f')
    AND   lower(substr(a.cookie_id,-3,1)) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f')
    GROUP BY a.data_date,cookie_type,AB
```

which one should i choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't do the same thing.  The second version should be:

```
 (CASE WHEN lower(substr(a.cookie_id, -3, 1) in ('2', '3', '5', '6', '8', 'b', 'c', 'd')  THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END) as AB,
```

This is the better way to write the logic, in my opinion, because it uses the specific SQL operand for this purpose.

As for performance, it won't matter.  The performance of the query is much more determined by the `from` and `group by` clauses than by `case` expressions in the `select`.